# How to enable label and textfield when combo box item selected

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox, jtextfield

I created one combobox with two item as " `Active` " and " `Droped` " then i take one `label` with `jtextfield` and write code for `enable and disable` of label and jtextfield in the jcomboobx `action event` so code is working but here one problem which is that label and jtextfield initially not disabled...when i select item " `Droped` " then select item " `Active` " after its going `disabled` otherwise  `initially` when run jframe, `label and jtextfield enabled` so i want `how to jlablel and Jtextfield enable when jcombobx select item " Droped " only`

**source code:**

```
private void wtdlActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

        txt_reason.setEnabled(false); //txt_reason is jTextField
        lab.setEnabled(false); //lab is jLabel

        if(wtdl.getSelectedItem().equals("Active")) //wtdl is jConobbox
        {
        txt_reason.setEnabled(false);
        lab.setEnabled(false);
        }
      else if(wtdl.getSelectedItem().equals("Droped"))
        {
        txt_reason.setEnabled(true); 
        lab.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

**check snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. If I may understand your question, you want to disable the JTextField when the JFrame loads?

Comment: thanks for reply @Michael Ardan. yes i want when i load jframe the  JTextField and jlabel both are disabled but when i select the "Droped" item from jcombobox then both are Enabled the JTextField and jlabel....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a method `updateState()` as following:

```
protected void updateState() {
    boolean enabled = wtdl.getSelectedItem().equals("Droped");
    txt_reason.setEnabled(enabled ); 
    lab.setEnabled(enabled );
}
```

and call it after you have initialized your components and in your `actionPerformed()`

Comment: @Guillaume Polet thanks for help dear sir and i have little problem, when i post code in netbeans but it giving me error ';'Expected and plz check snapshot link may you better understand http://i50.tinypic.com/2zyvtwg.jpg

Comment: @AyazAli Sorry, mistyped my code: there was an extra ')' at the end of `equals()`. Simply remove the last ')' on that line.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood:

You should add code to set the `JTextField` and `JLabel`  *disabled* via `setEnabled(false)` after the component(s) has been created.

If you are using a IDE Im sure you can set the property of the component by right clicking on it and navigating to properties (this will than of course become the default when `JFrame` is created).

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the JTextField once you have created the component. For example:
`JTextField txtYourTextField = new JTextField();`

txtYourTextField.setEnabled(false);